# Can't import PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2

Version:
Python:3.6.8 (32 bit)
PySide2: 5.15.0

my code:

```py
import PySide2.QtCore

print(PySide2.__version__)
```

but got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/7-Pycharm/contrl_sys_ui/test/qt_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PySide2.QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module was not found
```

Comment: Does PySide2 5.15.0 not support Python 3.6 32-bit version?

Comment: Did you got the solution ? I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried installing and importing in my Google collab, with following commands:

```
pip install PySide2
import PySide2.QtCore
print(PySide2.__version__)
```

The outputs were as follows:

[image]

But, my Python version is 3.6.9. However, Can you please try reinstalling this package and let us know?

Comment: I reinstalled the PySide2, but there are still mistakes. If I use ```import PySide2
print(PySide2.__version__)```, everything is ok. But when I use ```import PySide2.QtCore```, PyCharm will prompt "import error: DLL load failed"

Comment: how did you install PySide2?

Comment: @Raghvendra was it for 32bit or 64 bit ?